# Scale page to screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to scale the whole webpage based on screen size?
I want to make the webpage scaling depend on screen height or width, which is smaller.
It's not responsive web design because everything, including text and images, is scaling when the screen is changing and I want them still scaled in screen, so that I don't think I have to modify every CSS into percentage margin or size.
Any solution based on Javascript, CSS, or HTML/PHP would be helpful!

Comment: Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, there is no way to force the entire web page to scale dynamically. Nowadays most smaller devices such as smartphones will zoom out to fit the whole website on screen anyways. I know it will take some work, but you should consider leveraging your CSS to implement responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Andrew's comment, there are free templates out there that have this type of automatic scaling functionality. Bootstrap is one. You could start here:

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples